# scheduler.getScheduler() returns NULL

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, hazelcast

I am trying to implement a scheduler using quarts in distributed environment. I am using https://github.com/mufumbo/quartz-hazelcast to achieve it. But scheduler.getScheduler()  returns NULL. Someone please help me to understand the problem.

```
private static SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
public void startSchedulers() {
    try {
        scheduler.start();
        // define the job 
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ArchiveJob.class)
                .withIdentity("archiveJob", "group1")  
                .build();

        // Trigger the job
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("archiveTriger", "group1")
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInSeconds(60).repeatForever())
                .build();

        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
        scheduler.getScheduler().scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
    }
}
```